# jQuery UI Datepicker. Show one format, save other

Tags: jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI Datepicker.

```
var dates = $( "#checkinTxt").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        regional: "es",

});
```

I want the user to see the full dateFormat: `"dd-MM-yy" (25-March-2013)` after they choose the date, but keep the other dateFormat: `"yy-mm-dd"`, in the input field (or a hidden field)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI Datepicker supports `altField` and `altFormat` options.